# Probability Example - Multiple sub-items (easy)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm doing an exercise 1-3 from Probability and Statistics with Applications: A Problem Solving Text, By Leonard A. Asimow, Mark M. Maxwell:

A convenience store has three packages of plain M&M's and two packages of peanut M&M's, one package of dark chocolate M&M's, one package of peanut butter M&M's, and one package of almond M&M's.  Select 2 packages of candy. 
(b)  Assume the outcomes are equally likely.  Calculate the probability you select exactly one package of plain M&M's (and the other package is **not plain**-either peanut, dark chocolate, peanut butter, or almond). 
(c)  Calculate the probability of getting at least one package of plain M&M's.

To make enumeration easier, I assigned letters to subgroups: 
a=plain, 
b=peanut,  
c=dark chocolate,  
d=peanut butter,  
e=almond

For Part (B), there is already a post:  [What is probability of selecting one sub-item from multiple sub-items?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77295/what-is-probability-of-selecting-one-sub-item-from-multiple-sub-items).  I just had a one question:  How do you know when to treat subgroups as indistinguishable?  Do you always do that in a probability problem?  For example, initially, I treated any subsets of plain and peanut as the same, but actually the problem makes a difference.  So instead of $(a,a)$, you really would want to enumerate $(a_1,a_2),(a_1,a_3), (a_2,a_3)$.

Other then that, I understand there's 3 plain and 5 not plain, so the solution is of form:
$\cfrac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{8}{2}}.$

Part (c):  I know the solution is $\cfrac{18}{28}$ by enumeration, but I had a problem deriving it using combinations.  You have 2 slots, one of which must at least be plain.  I would represent this as $\binom{3}{1}$.  Now in the second slot you have 5 M&M's remaining that are not plain, but unlike part (b), you have 2 more additional M&M's that are plain which you could now include.  So I though the second combination would be $\binom{7}{1}$.  But if you do $\cfrac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{7}{1}}{\binom{8}{2}}$, you get the wrong answer.  I can back track and see that 7 should be a 6, but I don't understand why what I did is wrong.  Can someone please explain the correct thought process?

I could just use my answer from part (b) and realize that there are 3 combinations, $\binom{3}{2}$, of $a_1,a_2,a_3$ and just add that from my answer in part (b).  Is this the best way or can you do in one shot?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For at least one, calculate the probability of exactly one (already done) and add the probability of exactly two (done in a similar but simpler way than exactly one).

As to the question about distinct, it is often best to imagine that all the packages have secret ID numbers written on them, making them distinct.

There are other ways to solve the "at least one" problem. Let us calculate the probability of choosing **no** plain. Imagine the choices are made one at a time. The probability the first choice is not plain is $\frac{5}{8}$. Given that the first was not plain, the probability the second is not plain is $\frac{5}{7}$. So the probability neither is plain is $\frac{5}{8}\cdot \frac{4}{7}=\frac{5}{14}$. So the probability of at least one plain is $1-\frac{5}{14}=\frac{9}{14}$.

Comment: Whenever you have multi-subgroups and are calculating the probabilities, do you always decompose them into the various scenarios and then sum them together?  Is this always the method?

Comment: Also, lets say you're rolling two dice.  Would you say there are 36 or 72 outcomes?

Comment: About your first question. Decomposition (cases) is a useful technique. In quite a few cases, it is not the best technique. As a simple example, suppose we has $24$ plain and $65$ others, and picked $6$. If we want the probability of at least one plain, we can compute probability of $1$, $2$, and so on, and add up. But it is faster to find the probability of none, and subtract from $1$. As to your second question, the useful sample space has size $36$.

Comment: Thank you for all your help Andre.

Comment: You are welcome. Your urge to classify and find general methods is quite reasonable. And there *are* general methods. However, in problem solving, one often has to adapt, or combine.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I'm also looking for a methodology to attack or approach combinatorics/probability questions.  This branch of mathematics is much different than calculus, linear alg, and diffy Q's.  It's taking me some time to get used to.